# QM -group reps and transforming wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-representations

QM texts seem to have many ways of motivating the angular momentum operators and deriving the l and m quantum numbers . But the connection between physical rotaions in 3 dim space and an operator in hilbert space that is called " angular momentum" is still somewhat unclear to me

I found a set of notes on Lie Groups in Physics by Nobel prize winner 
Veltman - that seems to be particualry clear explanation of 
irreducible reps of SO(3) and angluar momentum operatiors

see on page 10 of     www.phys.uu.nl/~thooft/lectures/lieg07.pdf

He begins with discussion of general linear diffrential equations 
that have a set of solutioins . He then says that when a 3 dim rotation 
takes place a solution of the DE is then transformed into a linear 
mixture of other solutions

Is this true for all linear diffrential equations -??  or are these type of 
transformations amoung solutions in response to 3 dim rotations 
an assumption that is made about wavefunctions or about states in 
a Hilbert space as part of the assumptions of QM ?

THanks 
Len